# Is there a need for .scss to .css in Vite?

Tags: css, sass

Do I need to compile my .scss file to .css in my Vite project? Will it wont work if I just use the .scss extension

everything seems to work fine without the need to compile.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to compile .scss files to .css in a Vite project. Vite includes built-in support for Sass, so you can use the .scss extension in your project and Vite will automatically compile it to CSS for you. This means you do not need to use a separate tool to compile your Sass files, and you can use them directly in your project without any additional steps.

Comment: It's quite amazing how many posts on the internet and stackoverflow casually interchange saas and scss - they are not the same thing! The question posted here: 'Is there a need for .scss to .css in Vite?' There's no mention of saas. The highlighted text above groups saas and scss into 'them'?! So can I compile Sam Smith into CSS using this method?

Comment: SASS stands for syntactically awesome style sheets, Scss is SASS.  The . Sass extension however is an alternative sytax to . Scss, but both run on the SASS engine. So both of you are correct.  Also you typo'd Saas, the op said Sass not saas, which was correct.  Saas is software as a service and no one mentioned it, they said Sass.